# UIActivityViewController not sharing with Wechat

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, wechat

I am trying share image, url and text with the wechat but i am getting this message. I am simple using the UIActivityViewController for sharing the content with wechat. But not able to share.

[image]

here is my code:

```
 UIImage * shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"igo-logo-small"];
UINavigationController * nav = fromVC.navigationController;

// error handling
NSString * error = nil;
for (;;) {

    // sanity
    if (text == nil || url == nil || shareImage == nil || nav == nil) {

        error = @"arguments not all valid";
        break;
    }

    // setup share controller
    UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];
    NSArray *applicationActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];
    FilteredActivityViewController * activityController = [[FilteredActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[text, shareImage, url] applicationActivities: applicationActivities];

    if (activityController == nil) {

        error = @"share controller nil";
        break;
    }

    // success - made it to end
    [nav presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
        NSLog(@"completionWithItemsHandler, activityType: %@, completed: %d, returnedItems: %@, activityError: %@", activityType, completed, returnedItems, activityError);
        if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard"] && completed) {
            [MBProgressHUD showSuccessWithoutImage:@"Copied" toView:nav.view];
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you solve it? My app is showing the same, and it uses to work.

Answer (score 3):

I received the exact same error dialog and solved it as follows.
Passing just text would always produce this error. However, if I combined it with either an URL or an image then WeChat would proceed as normal.

I am certain this used to work at one time and it would be great if WeChat simply accepted text only -- just like all other apps do (WhatsApp, Line,...)

Answer (score 1):

For the bug "unable to share this type of content" in WeChat the important variable to check is the url. The following code works for me

```
 UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]   initWithActivityItems:@[@"SampleMessage", [UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleImage"], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

In your code I have doubt about your url variable. Can you check if it is a proper url as I can't see how you have initialised it in your code. Try the above code and see if it works for you or post your entire code of sharing so that we can help you to fix the issue.

Comment: This seems to be a little odd. Why must there be an image or URL to share? Can someone more familiar with WeChat shed some light?

Comment: Unfortunately WeChat is not accepting only text when we use it with UIActivityViewController so we have to add image/url for it to work.

Comment: Is there a way to add a bogus URL but then display full text. Seems like the text is quite limited as well. How to display full text?